# Counting objects and showing the results in Django

Tags: django, django-views, counting, tabular, annotate

I have a question regarding counting objects, filtering the results and finally putting them into my template.

in `Models.py`:

```
class Fms(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Department')
    date = models.DateField()
```

in `Views.py`:

```
def raport(request):
    raport = Fms.objects.filter(date__year='2013').extra(select={'month': "EXTRACT(month FROM date)"}).values('month', 'department').annotate(Count('department'))
    return render_to_response ('Fms/raport.html',
                               {'raport': raport},
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Question is, how to show a result in a table like:

[image: Result]

Or at least make it show each month and how many times department was mentioned in that month.

Comment: are you asking about what sql statement should you use, or how to display the information from request context in your template?

Comment: I would like to display the information from request in my template. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need something like:

```
{% for each_model in raport %}
    {{each_model.department}}
    {{each_model.date}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not pass a keyword to `annotate`, it uses the name of the field with `__count` appended to it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset To access that in your template you would simply do:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in raport %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.month }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.department__count }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

To display it horizontally...

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for item in raport %}
                <th>{{ item.month }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for item in raport %}
                <td>{{ item.department__count }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: After using your solution, the result looks like this: http://i47.tinypic.com/bjd3qf.jpg How can i get months horizontally and then show number of department occurences in those months  like in image attached in my first post? Regards